# how to only disable paypal button but enable paylater button?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am trying to enable only paypal 'paylater' button and nothing else. I am using this code.

I also want to get (in case of payin3 option the breakdowns of total amount) amounts in an array so that I could perform some action on that.

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxx&currency=GBP&components=buttons,messages&buyer-country=GB&enable-funding=paylater&disable-funding=card"></script>
<div data-pp-message data-pp-style-layout="text" data-pp-style-logo-type="inline" data-pp-style-text-color="black" data-pp-amount="170"></div>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '170'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any paypal options to achieve your goal - but you can certainly use css (display: none) to hide the button.

Comment: CSS is also not working due to cross origin domain issue :(

Comment: oh - I see. So the paypal content is rendered in an iframe. According to the SDK-Docs, the buttons are not always the same, so what you see might not be the same other users see: ```The buttons that display are decided automatically, based on a range of factors, including: Buyer country, Device type, Funding sources the buyer has opted to see. As a result, each buyer might see a unique combination of buttons.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fundingSource](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/#link-oninitonclick)

```
paypal.Buttons({
  fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYLATER,
  style: { color: 'gold' },
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '170'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Even though I have figured it out how to disable it by myself but still I am marking this answer is correct as it is correct one and may help someone. Thank you for your response

Comment: Also Preston Could you plz let me know how to get payin3 instalment amounts using javascript sdk. it will help me a lot. see pic in my question